# Undefined reference errors while linking in makefile

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling

I have a set of cross compiled dynamic libraries generated. While trying to link it, I am getting the following error:

> arm-linux-ld: xxx.so: undefined reference to symbol '__aeabi_uldivmod@@GCC_3.5'

Does anybody have any idea what I am missing?

Below is the libraries I am linking and the order of linking:

```
some user defined libraries + -lcrypto -lssl  -lz -lpthread  -lxml2    
-lcsvparser -lubox -lini -lyuarel -lsqlite3  -lcurl -lm -ldl -lrt -lc  -lgcc
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you build the libraries? Have you tested any of them? How big is your source code?

Comment: My source code is around 36 kb, I have tested the source code completely in a an x86  build environment. To run on an ARM v7 processor I cross compiled it with a compatible tool chain. But while linking the libraries I am getting this error.